# Seo friendly URLs - how to?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have URL like `domain.com/profile.php?id=username`, and I would like to rewrite it as a `domain.com/profile/username`. Can someone help me with it ? I have already tried to rewrite it .htaccess, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: It's working, but it won't load CSS & images.

Comment: For that add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: Still have a problem, it works fine now, but when I want to navigate somewhere else from domain.com/profile/username, URL stays with profile parameter, so if I want to navigate to domain.com/contact, it will be domain.com/profile/contact.

Comment: I've it exactly like that, but still happening.

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/i7kq33vqh/53309e0a/) that happens after directing from /profile/username to user.php from menu.